# Database encryption options for Ruby on Rails hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, encryption, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

One of the clients I'm working with is requesting that I encrypt my database. The problem is, none of my other clients need or care about this.

I am wondering two things:

1. How costly (performance) is it to encrypt my entire database? I.e. how much slower will my read / writes be?
2. Is there anyway I can provision a small separate DB, or segment my current DB on Heroku and host that one specific client's data (wherein their data is fully encrypted).

Thanks!
Ringo

Comment: Encryption isn't magic secret security sauce. Where will the keys be kept? Will they be stored encrypted and require an off-site passphrase to be manually entered when the app starts? etc. If you just encrypt the data then store the key in the DB, that's a total waste of time. The client should focus on their actual threat model - what are they trying to protect against?

Comment: See also: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12329652/398670, http://stackoverflow.com/a/8305335/398670, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12615409/398670